# Rails 4 - dynamically add nested json data in jsonb column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails 4 app, I have a jsonb column called 'deals_usage'.

I would like to set up the following :

- on create

  ```
  deals_usage= { }
  ```
- when a user loads deal number2 view (as an example), the attribute value change the value of deal_usage for the current user

  ```
  deals_usage= {
     { Deal 2 = { clicks_performed_by_user = 0, purchases_performed_by_user= 0 }
   }
  ```
- then if a user click something inside the Deal, the attribute value change to:

  ```
  deals_usage= {
     { Deal 2 = {clicks_performed_by_user = 1, purchases_performed_by_user= 0 }
  }
  ```

So if a user participated in deal 2 with 1 click and in Deal n°5 with 1 purchase the deal_usage would be.

```
     deals_usage={ 
         { Deal 2 = { clicks_performed_by_user = 1, purchases_performed_by_user= 0},
           Deal 5 = {clicks_performed_by_user = 0, purchases_performed_by_user= 1}
      }
```

Note: increments can only be +1 . If a user clicks: click+=1, if user purchase, purchase+=1. On this patter, it's quite simple.

Today I fail to achieve that. My current code below only does this:

- on create

  ```
   deals_usage= { }
  ```

I have successfully implemented a jsonb column for it.

- when a user loads deal number2 view (as an example), it changes the value of deal_usage for the current user

  ```
  deal_usage= { { clicks_performed_by_user = 0, purchases_performed_by_user= 0} }
  ```

And then I manage on each click and purchase to increment their values so that if user clicks in ANY DEAL, I get

```
    deal_usage= { { clicks_performed_by_user = 1, purchases_performed_by_user= 0} }
```

**BUT as you see I don't know on which Deal the click was performed. I don't know how to define in active record and save inside the database when clicks and purchases happen, when it comes to doing it PER DEAL.**

I think one of the challenge involve creating a sort of dynamic store accessors as the number and the id of deals vary, each user will participate in different deals, and so on...

Here is my current code

The click for example (but also purchase) work as shown below using ajax (there is no form)

**the_page.html**

```
<!-- Click on one of the tracked areas for deals -->
<div id="deal-zone">  
        <span>
          <!-- caution: link below is not looking for click_inside_deal.html.erb, it's looking for click_inside_deal.js.erb -->
          <%= link_to image_tag("image.png"), click_inside_deal_path, remote: true %>
        </span>

  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then this go to Routes to look for click_inside_deal_path

**Routes.rb**

```
match '/deals/:id',
    to:   'deals#click_inside_deal',
    via:  'get',
    as:   :click_inside_deal # path for rake route pathes
```

Then this route points to the Deals controller 'click_inside_deal':

**Deals_controller.rb**

```
class DealsController < ApplicationController

def show_deal_page   
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find params[:id]
    #pass rails variables to js views with gon

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # showcase.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @deal }
    end      

  end 

def click_inside_deal
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find params[:id]
    current_user.increment_per_deal_clicks_performed_by_user

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js 
    end    
  end    
end
purchase click_inside_deal
    @deal = Deal.friendly.find params[:id]
    current_user.increment_per_deal_purchases_performed_by_user

    respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :template => "deals/show_purchase_modal.js.erb" }
    end    
  end    
end
```

As you see there is no form but I increment the nb of clicks and purchase purely in ajax and using the method increment_per_deal_clicks_performed_by_user

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify

  # postgresql JSON attributes accessors  
  store_accessor :deals_usage,
                  # how to put here that the 2 following accessors are for EACH deal the user participate in ?
                  :clicks_performed_by_user,
                  :purchases_performed_by_user

 def increment_per_deal_clicks_performed_by_user
      self.update_attribute(:clicks_performed_by_user, self.clicks_performed_by_user += 1) 
    end

 def increment_per_deal_purchases_performed_by_user
      self.update_attribute(:purchases_performed_by_user, self.purchases_performed_by_user += 1) 
    end

def set_default_clicks_performed_by_user
      self.clicks_performed_by_user         ||= 0
    end 

def set_default_purchases_performed_by_user
      self.purchases_performed_by_user      ||= 0
    end
```

when clicked, a modal view appears

**click_inside_deal.js.erb**
(using hubspot modal alerts: http://github.hubspot.com/messenger/)

```
var msg;
msg = Messenger().post({

if xxx 
    message:  '<%= j render partial: "deals/failure" %>',
else
    message:  '<%= j render partial: "deals/description_of_deal" %>',
});
```

Note: I want to keep this jsonb column and not use has_many/has_many relations between deals and clicks or purchases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide with you an answer which leverages jsonb and the default update action so that you don't have to create specific actions for this behavior. The code that I will paste below solves your problem, but can further be improved (e.g. by using Ajax). Hope I could help ;)

**Database**

Assume table "deals" with at least the following fields:

id | deals_usage *where deals_usage is a jsonb column 
----------------------------------------------------------------------- 
1*  | {"clicks_performed_by_user": 0, "purchases_performed_by_user": 0} 
2*  | {"clicks_performed_by_user": 0, "purchases_performed_by_user": 0} 
3*  | {"clicks_performed_by_user": 0, "purchases_performed_by_user": 0} 
4*  | {"clicks_performed_by_user": 0, "purchases_performed_by_user": 0}

*number of deal (you may customize this to use another field)

**Migration** (create_deals.rb)

```
class CreateDeals < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :deals do |t|

      ## Properties
      t.jsonb :deals_usage, null: false, default: '{"clicks_performed_by_user": 0, "purchases_performed_by_user": 0}'

      ## Timestamps
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    ## Indexes
    add_index :deals, :deals_usage, using: :gin
  end
end
```

**Model** (Deal.rb)

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
 after_initialize :add_field_accessors

  def add_store_accessor field_name
    singleton_class.class_eval {store_accessor :deals_usage, field_name}
  end

  def add_field_accessors
    num_fields = deals_usage.try(:keys).try(:count) || 0
    deals_usage.keys.each {|field_name| add_store_accessor field_name} if num_fields > 0
  end
end
```

**View** (deals/edit.html.erb or other)

```
<%= form_for @deal do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :clicks_performed_by_user, :value => @deal.clicks_performed_by_user.to_i + 1 %>
  <%= f.submit "Click" %>
<% end %>

# I've separated the forms in order to become easier to understand, value is      
# passed trough an hidden field and we just let update do the rest.

# Of course you can still use your methods just point out :url to your actions
# and there set attribute with Object.update_attribute(:field, "value")

<%= form_for @deal do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :purchases_performed_by_user, :value => @deal.purchases_performed_by_user.to_i + 1 %>
  <%= f.submit "Purchase" %>
<% end %>
```

**View** (without form_for)

```
<!-- Click on one of the tracked areas for deals -->
<div id="deal-zone">  
  <span>
    <!-- leverage the update action with a link_to helper -->
    <%= link_to( "Click", deal_path(@deal, :deal => { :clicks_performed_by_user => @deal.clicks_performed_by_user.to_i + 1}), :method => :put) %>
  </span>
</div>
```

**View** (with Ajax)

```
<!-- Click on one of the tracked areas for deals -->
<div id="deal-zone">  
  <span>
    <!-- leverage the update action with a link_to helper -->
    <%= link_to( "Click", deal_path(@deal, :deal => { :clicks_performed_by_user => @deal.clicks_performed_by_user.to_i + 1}), :remote => true, :method => :put) %>
  </span>
</div>
```

**Controller** (expecting Ajax requests)

```
  # PATCH/PUT /deals/1
  # PATCH/PUT /deals/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @deal.update(deal_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @deal, notice: 'Deal was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @deal }
        format.js   { render nothing: true } # Change to what you want
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @deal.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

If you need any further explanation, feel free to contact me at anytime.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: thanks so much for your answer. Actually, it's my fault I was not precise enough in my question. I had left out the basic view and routes, thinking it had no impact on the answers... so I corrected this by  adding new elements (html/routes...)  in my question because I am indeed using ajax (already) and I don't have a form with form_for and so on.... I would like to use just ajax and a method that increments. You've already opened some ideas for me, would it be too much to ask if you can adjust your answre to what I added (ajax, no form if possible).

Comment: I've updated my answer, so that you can use a link_to (no need for remote or render javascript). For this, I recommend leveraging the native power of Rails routing instead of creating custom actions and routes.

Comment: thanks, i am going to try it tonight. I was using the routes match '/deals/:id',     to:   'deals#click_inside_deal',     via:  'get'... because when a user click, I also load a javascript modal so I needed a view:) I am going to try your method without routes...but not sure i could have the view without the route. Will add this modal view inside my question

Comment: also if you check my question, the store accessor and the deals_usgae belongs to user so user model. you have put deals_usage it seems inside model deal.rb. It's a mistake right? I'll use it as it is but put it inside User model. For example on user number 3 I have a column deals_usage with value { 5: { clicks: X, purchase Y} }  meaning the user 3, has done actions sindie the deal number 5 has clicked X times and made Y purchases

Comment: sindie the deal number 5 : misspelled=> wanted to write "when he was on the deal page (deal number 5)

Comment: I am trying to use your suggestion but I think there was a major misunderstanding: on my question I was saying that a user can go on a deal page and perform actions (clicks, purchases) and my goal was that when user clicks on certain parts inside the Deal show page, to trigger certain actions and notably to increment the User's click nb.  See next comment

Comment: So in User table, inside line 2 (user number 2), I could see the column deals_usage={ 
         { 3 = { clicks_performed_by_user = 1, purchases_performed_by_user= 0},# 2 means deal with id 3
           Deal 5 = {clicks_performed_by_user = 0, purchases_performed_by_user= 1} # 5 means deal with id 5
      }. But what you suggest is not really this, you add accessors and columns to Deal table...

Comment: Alright Mathieu, do you use IRC so that we can chat, maybe it is easier that way. I confess I was really eager to help and I believe I provided with all the elements you require to succeed. I was looking for my first bounty prize, but it seems my answer wasn't just good enough.

Comment: hey no worries. i will give the bounty as it's still the closest so far and really helped me a lot. i'm working in the nect few days to make it work and will give the bounty if it's still the closest answer. thanks jorge

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to store JSON as you describe. For example:

```
{ 
"2" => { clicks_performed_by_user: 0, purchases_performed_by_user: 1 }, 
"3" => { clicks_performed_by_user: 0, purchases_performed_by_user: 1 }
}
```

Where the number is the deal id. That said, there are better ways. Ideally you should create a many_to_many join table with user_id, deal_id and your two count columns. See 3.3.2 here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Then you can use SQL to manage your data, which will be impossible if you stuff it all in JSON.

===========================

Follow Up

Edit your model to store the data:

```
def increment_per_deal_purchases_performed_by_user(deal_id)
    self.deals_usage[deal_id] ||= {}
    self.deals_usage[deal_id]["purchases_performed_by_user"] ||= 0
    self.deals_usage[deal_id]["purchases_performed_by_user"] += 1
end
```

Comment: thanks, i know it's possible. but my question is how to change my models, my controllers and maybe other things so that accessors work, so that it saves in database what you suggest...i'd like real code change suggestions

Comment: i don't want to use many to many but this jsonb attribute for aop-related other issues

Comment: let me try it. would that be enough? :) i 'm going to try

Comment: Should work... just edited to automatically initialize the deal object also

Comment: Maybe you aren't including a deal_id when calling the method?

Comment: yes something like this. I'll move forward today and keep you informed.

Comment: It's not really working. It's not saving anything inside the table User. it stays empty : {} even if the user clicks.  Should i keep my store accessor like this inside the model ? shouldn't  I remove it or adjust it to the new proposed structure ? 
  store_accessor :deals_usage,                  
                  :clicks_performed_by_user,
                  :purchases_performed_by_user

Comment: For this example you only need "deals_usage", and you need a text field of the same name in your database.

Comment: of course I have it already. in my question, I was giving the current code and it was working. I was managing to update the deals_usage jsonb column and putting inside when a user click something like: { Deal 2 = { clicks_performed_by_user = 0, purchases_performed_by_user= 0 } but it was not related to a specific deal. so yes I have a working database column

Comment: I'll delve deeper in my app because it might be app-related and you might not have all the elements necessary to help. If needed, I'll update here the question.

Comment: I'm not an expert but could it be that in my table User the column deals_usage remains an empty kson ( {}) because in your suggestion it gives the value to sth in memory but I am not explicitly telling the app to write it inside the table's column. it 's like the difference between saying @user.example = 5 and saying @user.update(:example)= 5. maybe only the second can work in that case but i would not know how to use update or update_attribute to change a certain deal_id value inside the json